# Quick way to add a class to a django admin field?

Tags: python, django

Is there a quicker way to append a class name to an input field in Django Admin? e.g. I have a text field called 'markdown', and I want to add the class `markdown` to it, so I can easily apply a markdown editor in admin.

The result of this code is perfect. Just a bit of a PITA to apply this across all my admin forms..

I can't use `formfield_override` since not all my textareas are markdown.

```
class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        widgets = {
            'markdown': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'markdown'})
        }


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelAdminForm
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not creating a string which will hold the class name for each input you want to give it a class and then pass that string to `attrs`'s `class` key?

```
# forms.py

MARKDOWN = 'markdown'

class MyModelAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        widgets = {
            'markdown': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': MARKDOWN})
        }
```

Now you can reuse `MARKDOWN` to other `modelForm`s. Of course this does not solve the repetition but at least is less error prone.

Another solution is to use javascript (first include it via the [`class Media`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/) inside your `MyModelAdmin` class) and then inside it you should do something like that:

```
// myModelAdmin.js

const $ = django.jQuery;

$(function() {
    $('your-selectors').addClass('markdown');
});
```